# "mount" process lasts indefinitely

Tags: fstab

I edited my `/etc/fstab` file in order to mount an exFAT disk on startup.
This is how the entry for the disk that causes issues looks:

```
#hoarder
UUID=5C02-C749 /home/mike/hoarder exfat rw,user,uid=1000 0 0
```

The disk is succesfully mounted and works, but I found out that the `mount.exfat` process that mounted keeps being alive and running, I noticed this because after some time I saw my I/O performance drop and tried to understand why.

[image]

I have 2 other disks which are formatted in ext4 and they work flawlessly.

EDIT: I just noticed the same thing happens if I mount the drive manually after boot, the `mount.exfat` process keeps being alive after the disk was mounted.
If I do the same for an ext4 drive, this does't happen.

Comment: Which exfat driver do you use? I'm asking because you probably use `exfat-fuse` which is a userspace program which uses the `fuse` daemon (probably your `mount.exfat`) for mounting a filesystem. Your I/O performance drops probably because of another reason.

Comment: I am in fact using ex-fat fuse, so the process staying alive now makes sense. The fact that my I/O drops remains a mistery then, thanks for the help.

Comment: you may use the program `iotop` to get info about your I/O performance. Install with `sudo apt install iotop`.